# How to store a MD5 hashed object as as a string?

Tags: python-3.x, hash, sqlite

I'm trying to find out how i can store a hashed object as a string.
I've got a section of code that compares what a user entered against what is stored in a Sqlite3 database and then allows them access or not depending on if the username and password is correct. T make it secure i hashed the password in the database and what the user enters is hashed as well, they are them meant to be compared, but when it goes to check it gives out the line in the shell;

```
sqlite3-interfaceerror-error-binding-parameter-0-probably unsupported type
```

Ive been told this is because a hash isnt a string, so how do i make a hash object into a string?? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks, Sam.

Also if it helps this is the full section of code as well.

def click(button):
    if button == "Cancel":
       login.stop()

```
if button == "Register":
   login.stop()
   register.go()



else:
   usr = login.getEntry("Username")
   pwd = login.getEntry("Password") #collects entry of password & username

###MD5 HASHING###
pwdencypt = hashlib.md5(pwd.encode('utf-8')) #makes the encypted password using md5 hashing
print(pwdencypt.hexdigest())
pwd2 = pwdencypt

conn = sqlite3.connect("uHubDatabase.db")
cursor = conn.cursor() #connects to database

###USERNAME SECTION###
find_user=("SELECT Username FROM UserTable WHERE Username = ?") #sets the finding of the username from the database as a varaible 
cursor.execute(find_user,[(usr)])


founduser = str(cursor.fetchall())
print(founduser)
removechars = "'(),[]" #Avoids the error of special characters caused by the database outputting strings (Text)
for char in removechars:
    founduser = founduser.replace(char,'')

###PASSWORD SECTION###
find_pass=("SELECT Password FROM UserTable WHERE Password = ?") #sets the finding of the password from the database as a varaible 
cursor.execute(find_pass,[(pwd2)])

foundpass = str(cursor.fetchall())
print(foundpass)
removechars = "'(),[]" #Avoids the error of special characters caused by the database outputting strings (Text)
for char in removechars:
    foundpass = foundpass.replace(char,'')

###DATA VARIABLE CHECKS###
print("This is from Database(Username)",founduser) 
print("This is whats inputed",usr) 
print("This is from Database(Password)",foundpass) 
print("This is whats inputed",pwd)
print("This is pwd but encypted",pwdencypt.hexdigest())

if founduser == usr and foundpass == pwdencypt: # If correct
    print("SUCESS")
    login.stop()
    home.go()

else: #if incorrect
    print("FAIL")
    login.retryBox("INCORRECT LOGIN", "The Username or Password entered are incorrect. Please try again.")
print("User:", usr, "Pass:", pwd)

conn.close() #closes connection
```

For some reason the code is out of alignment when i paste it in here so ignore that, that isn't the case in my program. Imported modules include sqlite3 and Appjar which is like tkinter.

Comment: What have you stored in the DB? How did you store it?

Comment: Just as the string of characters the hashing outputs when you make it Print. I used DBVeiwer to do it for testing.

Comment: The hash object does not output anything useful when you print it itself. What exactly did you store?

Comment: When you print them they print something like this c5ghi69heo339jlowp. I turned the word into that and stored it in the database as a string. Then the password system you transform the same word into the same string of characters and compare them.

Comment: @CL. Then it lets you in if they are the same, it worked when it was just the normal strings perfectly.

Comment: Why are you printing the result of `hexdigest()` and not the object itself?

Comment: @CL. Didn’t know?? So can I compare just the objects? If so how can I’ve this all to work. Thanks.

Comment: I already told you in the previous question that you cannot store the object itself in the DB.